# Replace multiple new lines with a single newline

Tags: php, regex, duplicates, preg-replace, newline

How do I replace multiple consecutive newlines with one newline. There could be up to 20 newlines next to each other. For example

```
James said hello\n\n\n\n Test\n Test two\n\n
```

Should end up as:

```
James said hello\n Test\n Test two\n
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$str = "Hello\n\n\n\n\nWorld\n\n\nHow\nAre\n\nYou?";
$str = preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $str);
print($str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Improving on Marc B's answer:

```
$fixed_text  = preg_replace("\n(\s*\n)+", "\n", $text_to_fix);
```

Which should match an initial newline, then at least one of a group of any amount of whitespace followed by a newline and replace it all with a single newline.

Comment: With php 7 this causes the following error `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '+' in...`

Comment: The modifier + must follow a letter or character group. Did you use that whole regex or a variation of it?

Comment: I used the entire code snippet exactly as posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fixed_text = preg_replace("\n+", "\n", $text_to_fix);
```

This should do it, assuming that the consecutive newlines are truly consecutive and don't have any whitespace (tabs, spaces, carriage returns, etc...) between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'James said hello\n\n\n\n Test\n Test two\n\n';
echo preg_replace('{(\\\n)\1+}','$1',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex:

- `+` means "one or more of the previous expression"
- `{2,}` means "two or more of the previous expression"

For the requirements in this question, there is no point replacing a single `\n` with a single `\n` because nothing changes for that substring. In other words, `/\n+/` is simply doing more work than necessary.

It makes much more sense to use a ranged quantifier of two or more.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZT7gL))

```
$string = "James said hello\n\n\n\n Test\n Test two\n\n";
echo json_encode(
    preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n", $string)
);
```

Output:

```
"James said hello\n Test\n Test two\n"
```

---

In other situations, it may be advantageous to replace newline sequences that may be from different operating systems with `\R`. This metacharacter matches `\r\n` or `\n`. Here is a modified pattern which will replace two or more newline sequences with the server's designated newline character sequence:

```
$string = "James\r\n said\n\r\n hello\r\n\r\n\r\n Test\n Test two\n\n";
echo json_encode(
    preg_replace("/\R{2,}/", PHP_EOL, $string)
);
// "James\r\n said\n hello\n Test\n Test two\n"
//       ^^^^----treated as one newline character sequence
```