# PHP replace double-lines with one HTML Break

Tags: php, replace, double, line, break

I am trying to replace all \n\n on my server with the `<BR>` tag so that a single \n does not turn into `<BR>`.

Example:

```
Hello,\n\nThis is an\nexample.\n\nThanks!
```

goes to:

```
Hello,<BR>This is an\nexample,<BR>Thanks!
```

(notice the single \n was not replaced)

When I do the following in PHP, it does not replace the two lines with a break:

```
$str = str_replace("\n\n", "<br />", $str);
```

Comment: The correct technique can be found at [Replace multiple new lines with a single newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70914630/2943403), just change the replacement parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\n` are actually `\r\n` (which means the input came from a Windows operating system), I suggest you normalize you newlines to the *nix standard first with the following regular expression:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\r\n?~', "\n", $str);
```

Then, your original snippet will work ([demo](http://codepad.org/NZOSUDCr)):

```
$str = str_replace("\n\n", '<br />', $str);
```

---

You could also just do:

```
$str = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '<br />', $str);
```

But that wouldn't work if the input came from Linux or a old Mac OS (which only uses `\r`).

Comment: @Bailey: Can you please post the output of `var_dump(implode('|', array_map('ord', str_split($str))));`?

Comment: string(142) "72|101|108|108|111|44|13|10|13|10|84|104|105|115|32|105|115|32|97|110|13|10|101|120|97|109|112|108|101|46|13|10|13|10|84|104|97|110|107|115|33"

Comment: I'm going to assume |13|10|13|10| is the \n\n, but I don't know what is wrong. :/

Comment: @Bailey: That's what's wrong, I'll post a solution in a second.

Comment: Neither of these work still... :/ I tried: $source = str_replace('\r\n\r\n', "<br />", $source); (I changed the var to $source)

Comment: @Bailey: It works for me as you can see (http://codepad.org/NZOSUDCr) are you sure you're not missing anything - either in the solution or the ASCII vector you gave me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11962/discussion-between-bailey-and-alix-axel)

Comment: `~\r\n?~` ?  The `\n` is not the optional character when trying to match newline sequences across different operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double escape your characters:

Try:

```
$str = str_replace("\\n\\n", "<br />", $str);
```

Comment: Still does nothing. These \n values are coming from MySQL, and being entered via a textarea. Would that affect anything?