# How to preserve whitespace with some restrictions with php?

Tags: php, html, newline

I am trying to build an site where people write and post it to the database. The text is written in `<textarea>` and I want to preserve the whitespaces as formatting.

For example, users have to press `ENTER` to get to a new line from the current one they were typing on, after that, if they want to press `ENTER` again by writing nothing, that means there will be two new lines, I want to keep the two or more than two new lines restricted to just one blank line.

Stack Overflow has this feature, while writing this line, I pressed enter thrice from the last line, but you can only see one white space.

[image: As I pressed enter 3 times, three <br> were created resulting in three white spaces]

How do I achieve this with PHP? I have tried `nl2br()` but that seems to change every `\n` to `<br \>`. How do I solve this issue?

**The actual source code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="ab">
</textarea>
<button>Sub</button></form>
<?php

$post= preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", $_POST['ab']);
echo nl2br($post);
 
 //echo str_replace($find,$replace,$post);

 
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the output html source:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="ab">
</textarea>
<button>Sub</button></form>
This is a single line.<br />
now I pressed enter,<br />
<br />
<br />
three spaces below (should show only 1 whitespace)</body>
</html>
```

Look at the `<br />` created by the `nl2br`, I want the consecutive `<br /r>` to be `<p>...</p>`.

**This is what I want to be the output html source:**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="ab">
    </textarea>
    <button>Sub</button></form>
    This is a single line.<br />
    now I pressed enter,<br />
    <p>
    three spaces below (should show only 1 whitespace)</p></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you want to prevent it as people are typing in the textarea, or just clean up multi-line blanks after the form's submitted?

Comment: I want to clean up the multi-line breaks after submission.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052792/

Comment: @mark.hch It still doesn't work.

Comment: This does not work is not a useful information. You should post the exact incoming data from ` $_POST['ab']` and give an example of the desired output for that specific input. Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @maxhb, look at the html source output in my question.

Comment: Did see that but where is the input? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @maxhb That's all the source code I have got. Just run the first one and verify.

Comment: `rtrim($textarea);` ? will remove trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Refined my answer based on your new input:

```
$input = "This is a single line.\nnow I pressed enter,\n\n\nthree spaces below (should show only 1 whitespace)";

$output = preg_replace('/\n\n+([^\n]+)/', "\n" . '<p>$1</p>', $input);
echo nl2br($output);
```

Output:

```
This is a single line.<br />
now I pressed enter,<br />
<p>three spaces below (should show only 1 whitespace)</p>
```

Comment: look at the html source output in my question. @maxhb

Comment: try doing it like this `$input=$_POST['ab']; $output = preg_replace('/\n\n+([^\n]+)/', "\n" . '<p>$1</p>', $input);
echo nl2br($output);` Since you are taking `\n` directly into the string, it's working, but it doesn't work in the case of `textarea` in this method @maxhb

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly on Windows, where a newline is `\r\n`, not `\n` like other systems.  In fact according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area) browsers are supposed to normalise newlines from textareas to `\r\n` always.  So maybe that's the problem.

You want to leave single newlines alone, 2 newlines stays as 2 newlines, but 3 or more newlines should collapse to 2 newlines.  So try:

```
$post=preg_replace('/(\r\n){3,}/', "\n\n", $_POST['ab']);
echo nl2br($post);
```

To collapse 2 or more newlines to properly closed `<p>`s, as you have in your example output, is a bit harder and I'm not sure you can do it reliably, as it relies that the user create 2 newlines to indicate the start of the `<p>` and another 2 newlines for the end.  If they did not include the 2 ending newlines, you have no end marker for your regex and it will fail to match.  Safer to stick with 2 `<br>`s I think.

As an aside, "whitespace" means any space characters, including spaces, tabs, and newlines; "spaces" means spaces, as between consecutive words; "newlines" means line breaks.  Your question mixes up and interchanges these terms, and made it quite hard to understand on the first few reads.

Comment: Works great! But can you help me specify a css rule to decrease or increase the line-spacing in case of two newlines (which are replaced with `<br>`)? @don'tpanic

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee That's really a separate question but - I don't believe you can style  `<br>`, and if you modify line-height of the containing element it will affect the lines between text as well.  Maybe you could instead change the preg_replace() to replace 3+ newlines with `<p class='spacer'></p>` instead of `\n\n`, and then control the height of those by having `.spacer {line-height: 1.5;}` (or whatever) in your CSS.  Bit clunky but should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
$value = preg_replace('/\n\n+/', "\n\n", $value);
```

That is, replace any sequence of more than two newlines with just one.

Comment: Well, it definitely "works" — that code will replace any series of two or more `\n` characters with just two. If it's not doing what you expect, can you post an example of the data before transformation and what exactly needs to be transformed?

Comment: This is the new code- 
`$post= preg_replace('/\n\n+/', "\n\n", $_POST['ab']); echo nl2br($post);` and this is the output-

`john DOE<br />
<br />
john doe<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
john doe`

Comment: From that output it looks like there are spaces in between the newline characters there. (Or are they perhaps `CRLF` pairs?)

Comment: All I did was type 'john doe' on the text area and pressed enter arbitrarily and repeated it thrice.

Comment: The spaces you see are actually different lines in the source code. I had to copy it in one line to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
$post= preg_replace('/(\n\s*){2,}/', '<br>', $_POST['ab']);
echo nl2br($post);
```

Now the questions is: Why did I use that regex? It's because textarea leaves one space after every line. To avoid that problem I used an extra `\s*`. So the PHP will from:

```
a

b


c
```

to

```
a<br>
<br>b<br>
<br>c
```

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Yes, it solves that problem, but I want users to be able to output one single blank line with two or more newlines, i.e., if I press enter once, it should work as a `<br />` in the output, but if I press enter twice or more, it should make a new para with `<p>`. @PDKnight

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee Edited.